# Gorenstein property from initial ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-bases

My question is:

If $I$ is a homogenous ideal of $S=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $in_{<}(I)$ is the initial ideal of $I$, with respect to a term order $<$ on $S$, then $S/I$ is Gorenstein if and only if $S/in_{<}(I)$ is Gorenstein.

- If $S/in_{<}(I)$ is Gorenstein then $S/I$ is Gorenstein from Corollary 3.3.5 of Monomial Ideals by Herzog and Hibi;
- If $S/I$ is Gorenstein then $S/in_<(I)$ is Gorenstein ???

It looks so from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11923#:%7E:text=Let%20I%20be%20a%20homogeneous,and%20of%20S%2FJ%20coincide) but I'm not sure at 100%.